# Запись результата в CSV файл на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, graph

Нужно было написать программу, которая генерирует граф с случайной связностью и представить его в виде списков смежности и сохраняет эти списки в формате CSV.
Вывод списков через print() я сделал, расскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести результаты в CSV файл, чтобы в каждой отдельной строке был список смежности для определённой вершины.

```
import random
n = 5
matrix = [[random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    matrix[i][i] = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j]
print(matrix)
for i in range(n):
    print('Вершина', i+1, 'имеет связь с вершинами: ', end='')
    for j in range(n):
        if j == n-1 and matrix[i][j] != 0:
            print(j+1)
            continue
        elif j == n-1 and matrix[i][j] == 0:
            print()
        if matrix[i][j] != 0:
            print(j+1, end=' ')
```

В результате выполнения программы для матрицы 5x5 программа выводит следующие данные:
Вершина 1 имеет связь с вершинами: 2 3 4 5
Вершина 2 имеет связь с вершинами: 1 3 4
Вершина 3 имеет связь с вершинами: 1 2
Вершина 4 имеет связь с вершинами: 1 2 5
Вершина 5 имеет связь с вершинами: 1 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import random
n = 5
matrix = [[random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    matrix[i][i] = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j]
print(matrix)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as g:
    for i in range(n):
        print('{},'.format(i+1), end='', file=g)
        for j in range(n):
            if j == n-1 and matrix[i][j] != 0:
                print('{},'.format(j+1), file=g)
                continue
            elif j == n-1 and matrix[i][j] == 0:
                print("", file=g)
            if matrix[i][j] != 0:
                print('{},'.format(j+1), end='', file=g)
```